# Tensorflow, multi-label confusion matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, confusion-matrix, multilabel-classification

I am trying to figure out how to the generate a confusion matrix for a multi-label classification task using neural networks. I previously managed to calculate the accuracy using the function "intersection", since for that I did not care about any ordering.

```
intersection = tf.sets.set_intersection(predictions, labels)
```

However, in order to calculate the confusion matrix, I do care about the indexing order of the predictions/labels. And since the labels have always the same value (`1,1` or `0.5,0.5`) there is no possible sorting according to higher/lower value.

I wonder:

**1) Is it possible to calculate a confusion matrix for the multi-label classification task?**

**2) How would that be implemented ?**

**3) How can you handle the case of failure in predicting both labels? Since it is not possible to know which confusion belongs to which prediction.**

**4) What is the logic behind the sorting of the function tf.nn.top_k()**

Below I show an example of the code that I was trying to use.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

Z = np.array([[7.0, 3.0, 5.0, 1.0, 0.0, 6.0],[2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 3.25, 2.2], [2.0 , 5.0, 1.0, 7.0, 0.0, 8.0]])
Y = np.array([[0.5, 0, 0, 0.0, 0, 0.5],[0, 0.0, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0], [0,0,0,0.5,0,0.5]])

_, predicted_softmax = tf.nn.top_k(tf.nn.softmax(Z), k = 2, sorted = False)
_ , labels = tf.nn.top_k(Y, k = 2, sorted = False)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # reshape to (6,1) because there is 2 correct values per sample(2*3)
    print(predicted_softmax.eval().reshape(6,1))
    print(labels.eval().reshape(6,1))
    predicted = predicted_softmax.eval().reshape(6,1)
    labels_idx = labels.eval().reshape(6,1)

class_labels = np.arange(6)
cnf_matrix_train = confusion_matrix(labels_idx, predicted, labels = class_labels)

print(cnf_matrix_train)
```

I don't really get why the output of predicted_softmax is:

```
[[5] [0] [4] [2] [3] [5]] ,
```

I was expecting [5] [3] for the last two terms. There is no any logic to this output. In the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/top_k) they don't specify anything about the ordering in the case that `sorted = False` thought, but I was expecting some consistent behavior.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is it possible to calculate a confusion matrix for the multi-label classification task?

Yes and no. You can only calculate a TN (true negative), TP (true positive), FN (false negative), FP (false positive) matrix for each class and derive some [other metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix#Table_of_confusion) based on this. It will not show you, how a specific class has been mis-classified as a specific other class, but only *that* is has been misclassified and *how* (FN or FP).

[image: 2×2 confusion matrix]
Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix)

> 2. How would that be implemented ?

You could simply use [MultiLabelConfusionMatrix](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/MultiLabelConfusionMatrix) from the TensorFlow add-on package. It gives you just that: a 2x2 matrix *for each class*, containing TN, TP, FN and FP.

*Note that the implementation currently seems to assume that `y_pred` and `y_true` are binary tensors, i.e. consists of only `0`s and `1`s ([cast to `int`](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/blob/v0.15.0/tensorflow_addons/metrics/multilabel_confusion_matrix.py#L132-L133)).*

> 3. How can you handle the case of failure in predicting both labels? Since it is not possible to know which confusion belongs to which prediction.

Exactly. You can't.

> 4. What is the logic behind the sorting of the function `tf.nn.top_k()`

The [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/top_k) says:

> If `true` the resulting `k` elements will be sorted by the values in descending order.

For example, `tf.nn.top_k([10, 3, 1, 11], k=3)`, *could* return `[10, 3, 11]` (no order).

When sorting, `tf.nn.top_k([10, 3, 1, 11], k=3)` returns `[11, 10, 3]` (descending order).

(for clarity, please ignore for a second, that it would of course return a tensor, not a regular list)